# What is the Google Apps Script equivalent of Python's re.fullmatch?

Tags: python, regex, google-apps-script

I wrote a script in python that functions exactly as I need it to, but it doesn't look like Google Apps Script has the regex fullmatch method in the documentation. Essentially, I have a user inputted string, and I'd like to verify that the string matches a regular expression in entirety; a "full match". I'm familiar enough with Google Apps Script to convert the python script into GAS, but need help with the workflow, and potentially a different logical approach to this given GAS doesn't seem to have fullmatch available. The code below is the python script for reference.

```
import re

def is_valid(text, valid_styles):

    good_string_found = re.fullmatch(r'(([A-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s-\s([0-9]+)x?;\n)+', text)

    if good_string_found is None:
        return False, 1

    for each_item in text.split(";\n")[: len(text.split(";\n")) - 1]:

        style_number, size = each_item.split(" - ")[0], each_item.split(" - ")[1]
        valid_sizes = ["4","5","6","6x","7","8","10","12","14","16"]

        if style_number not in valid_styles or size not in valid_sizes:
            print("First error found in: " + style_number + " - " + size)
            return False, 2

    return True, 0

user_entry = "CS 101 - 8;\nCS 102 - 10;\nCS 104 - 6x;\n"
valid_style_numbers = ["CS 101", "CS 102", "CS 103", "CS 104"]
validity, error = is_valid(user_entry, valid_style_numbers)

if validity is False and error == 1:
    print("User entered string did not:\n- Match regex expected input")
elif validity is False and error == 2:
    print("User entered string did not:\n- Contain a valid style number\n- Contain a valid size")
elif validity is True:
    print("Proper scan")
```

Comment: GAS is just JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert your python script to Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

In this answer, in order to check the full match of `text`, the regex of `^(([A-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s-\s([0-9]+)x?;\n)+$` is used. And `test` is used for this situation.

#### Sample script 1:

This is a test script for the full match.

```js
const text1 = "CS 101 - 18;\nCS 102 - 10;\nCS 104 - 6x;\n";
const res1 = (/^(([A-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s-\s([0-9]+)x?;\n)+$/).test(text1);
console.log(res1)

const text2 = "CS 1foo01 - 18;\nCS 102 - 10;\nCS 104 - 6x;\n";
const res2 = (/^(([A-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s-\s([0-9]+)x?;\n)+$/).test(text2);
console.log(res2)
```

- I think that `^([A-Z]+\s[0-9]+\s-\s[0-9]+x?;\n)+$` can also be used.

#### Sample script 2:

When your python script is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

```
function is_valid(text, valid_styles) {
  const good_string_found = (/^(([A-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s-\s([0-9]+)x?;\n)+$/).test(text);
  if (!good_string_found) return [false, 1];
  let items = text.split(";\n");
  items.pop();
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const each_item = items[i];
    const [style_number, size] = [each_item.split(" - ")[0], each_item.split(" - ")[1]];
    const valid_sizes = ["4","5","6","6x","7","8","10","12","14","16"];
    if (!valid_styles.includes(style_number) || !valid_sizes.includes(size)) {
      console.log("First error found in: " + style_number + " - " + size);
      return [false, 2];
    }
  }
  return [true, 0];
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const user_entry = "CS 101 - 18;\nCS 102 - 10;\nCS 104 - 6x;\n";
  const valid_style_numbers = ["CS 101", "CS 102", "CS 103", "CS 104"];
  const [validity, error] = is_valid(user_entry, valid_style_numbers);
  if (!validity && error == 1) {
    console.log("User entered string did not:\n- Match regex expected input");
  } else if (!validity && error == 2) {
    console.log("User entered string did not:\n- Contain a valid style number\n- Contain a valid size")
  } else if (validity) {
    console.log("Proper scan")
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: This was awesome, took a little bit of modifying but worked perfectly. Interesting to see someone else's code, like I've never used "const" or "let". To make it work in my .gs file, I had to switch the const to var, remove the let from the for loop, and instead of .includes, I needed to use indexOf() == -1. Your .test worked perfectly, it was exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: @Lucas Bassoli Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.